# glossaries first use style

Tags: luatex, glossaries, package-options

after searching for like an hour, I still cannot find out how to do the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, openright]{report}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{test}{name={TEST},description={This is a test entry}}

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossaries

First: \gls{test}.
Second: \gls{test}.

\end{document}
```

This prints: `This is a test entry (TEST)` in the glossary, `TEST` on first use (and `TEST` on subsequent uses).

How can I change the appearance of the first use from `TEST` to `TEST (This is a test entry)`? I think that there is a `short-long` style option to do this, but I do not know how to apply it to my first entry (or if this even is the way to go).

Thanks a ton in advance for any help supplied.

(I use LuaTeX to compile because I also use the `minted` package)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I updated the code sample to be a working, minimal example. I tested it and the output indeed is as described.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple version using `glossaries-extra`.

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, openright]{report}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle{short-long}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newabbreviation{test}{TEST}{This is a test entry}


\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossaries

First: \gls{test}.
Second: \gls{test}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to put `\setabbreviationstyle` before `\newabbreviation`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thank you. I should recompile with auxiliary files deleted nex time :)

Comment: In this case it's not noticeable because `long-short` is the default for the `abbreviation` category, so it's already set (but it's useful to include it in examples for illustrative purposes). :-)